# Approval before I modify the form factor of an ATX PSU

Tags: power-supply, modeling, atx

I want to use an ATX PSU with my home build 3d printer but there is not enough space to fit it because of the height. Initially while designing the printer I planned to use an LED strip PSU. Now I realized when I opened the ATX PSU that there is enough free space after the fan mounted at the top is removed. I am planning to replace the big fan with two small ones mounted at the sides and then cut and refold the metal casing to the height just enough for the internal components.

I am making a big mistake?
what safety issues should I be worried about?

Comment: Have you thought about just getting a smaller one?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem if you:

1. Make sure you don't short anything out.
2. Ensure enough cooling via the new fans to compensate for the one you are removing.
3. That the new fans don't leave a pocket of air or under cooled part because of a change in direction/blocked path.

Easier solutions would be to either get a smaller power supply, mount it only partially in, or mount it externally and feed the wires through.

There are a ton of different power supply form factors. ATX supply only refers to the power output and connectors for a standard ATX compatible pc/motherboard/peripherals. Some are shorter, longer, wider, thinner, all four sides smaller, weird L shapes, etc.

Comment: Thanks but are there really smaller ATX PSUs?

Comment: I also want to fully mount it under the printer because I will be moving it around a lot.

Comment: PS-II, PS-III, SFX, TFX, all are ATX power supplies. A google for `smaller atx power supply` shows a bunch. Hell, I got one that's 90 Watts, and the size of two 3.5mm hard drives stacked together. Perfect for a mini atx/itx pc. So yes.